# How to install a theme color in vba

Tags: vba, colors

I just downloaded a color theme on [that link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503103/best-background-color-for-your-editor) (a vssetting file) and would like to know how to install it in VBA.

I have the file but no option to put it into VBA. How do I do that?

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve... If you want to change background color of CodePane editor, you should use Tools->Options, bookmark: Editor format.

Comment: Those are for Visual Studio, not VBA.

Comment: Removed greeting and thanks -- these are discouraged as they add nothing to the question. Formatted link properly, and stated the question explicitly.

Comment: Thanks Maciej Los and braX  :) ! Bob Dalgleish , I just tried to be polite and thankful...

Answer (score 6):

You can't use a `.vssetting` file, that's a Visual Studio thing - the VBE wouldn't know what to do with it.

Its colors are "configurable" through the Tools > Options menu; they're the same rather limited 16-bit colors from 1997... and there's no file you can import that will make a "theme" ([a .reg file could act like it, perhaps](https://superuser.com/a/315695/165271))

There *is* a hack, though - you can [hex-edit VBE7.DLL and change the available colors to whatever you like](https://github.com/dimitropoulos/VBECustomColors). Obviously the risk is that you completely wreck VBA in every single VBA host application at once, but hey shiny colors are worth it eh?

[image: image from https://github.com/dimitropoulos/VBECustomColors/blob/master/README.md]

The only thing I'm seeing that's remotely close to "theming" the VBE (and doesn't involve rewriting VBA itself) is what we want to achieve in [Rubberduck](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) (an OSS VBIDE add-in project I manage) by version 3.0 (we just kicked off the v2.1.x cycle), when we inject our own AvalonEdit WPF code pane into the VBE, implement our own *IntelliSense* and take full control of the VBE code panes' appearance and functionality - but there's **a lot** of work to be done before we can even dream of shipping that wet dream of a feature - so if you know a bit of C# and WPF, by all means join the Rubberduck dev team and help us do it!

---

**Update - March 2023** work has actually started on this now, and will indeed ship with Rubberduck 3.0 (still too early for a timeline though). You can join the Rubberduck3 project with a GitHub account, devs hang out on a [dedicated Discord server](https://discord.gg/MYX9RECenJ).

Comment: Thanks for the precision of the file. I will change manually in Tools > Options menu; thanks

Comment: @MC_B you're welcome. Feel free to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), for this question, the previous ones, and any future one you might ask on this site.